# how insert php variable inside a href to create link from that retrieve result of the variable?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, href

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("databasename") or die (mysql_error());

$sqlmydata = mysql_query("SELECT id, label, title, info, body FROM table LIMIT 0,10");

// Build the Output Section Here
$outputListdata1 = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqldata)){ 

    $id = $row["id"];
    $label = $row["label"];
    $title = $row["title"];
    $info = $row["info"];
    $body = $row["body"];

    $outputListdata1 .= '<div class="content1">
                    <a href= "#" >' .$title. '</a>
                    </div><!-- end of content1 -->

                    <div class="content2">
                    ' .$info. '
                    </div><!-- end of content2 -->';
} // close while loop
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>my site</title>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="container">
        <?php print "$outputListdata1"; ?> 
    </div><!-- end of container -->

</body>
</html>
```

look at the line14 in $outputListdata1 where $title is placed in between  href:

`<a href="#" >' .$title. '</a>`

i want to insert a $label variable in place of # inside the href. And so, it should display the result of the variable from my database.

`<a href="$label" >' .$title. '</a>`

For example:

if my database have the result for the $label variable is karthik means then it should look like(consider  variable $title has the result as fan of stack overflow),

`<a href="karthik" > fan of stack overflow</a>`

i know my question maybe simple or tough but i'm 100% sure you guys come forward with an answer..thanks in advance.

(note: this is my second question so plz excuse it my questioning method is awkward)

Comment: So do the same like you did with the title. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: can you write it with my code example plz... cos when i insert <a href="$label">' .$title. '</a> like this in the $outputListdata1 then it shows me error..can you understand ? plz help to cross this bridge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert the $Label Var in the Attribute:

```
<?php 

$outputListdata1 .= '<div class="content1">
                     <a href= "' .$label. '" >' .$title. '</a>
                     </div><!-- end of content1 -->
                     <div class="content2">' .$info. '</div><!-- end of content2 -->';

?>
```

You should learn the Basics of PHP, maybe do a Tutorial like this: [php-for-the-absolute-beginner](http://devzone.zend.com/6/php-101-php-for-the-absolute-beginner/).

Comment: thanks and sure i'll learn in coming days from good mind people like you. thank u for answer my question.. can you tell me how insert two variables in a href ..for example: <a href= "' .$label. '.' .$label. '" >' .$title. '</a> is it right?

Comment: `<a href= "' .$label.$label. '" >' .$title. '</a>` The `.` connects 2 Strings. The `'` just marks the star/tend of a String, but becouse you want to connect 2 Variables you dont need the `'` there. Yours Would Create the text 'labeltext.labeltext'

Answer (score 2):

You can write php in line with HTML, with the echo command you can output variables/strings into the HTML that will be sent to the user

`<a href="<?php echo $var1; ?>" > <?php echo $var2; ?></a>`

Comment: can you write it with my code example plz... cos when i insert <a href="$label">' .$title. '</a> like this in the $outputListdata1 then it shows me error..can you understand ? plz help to cross this bridge :(

Comment: yes i tried in what you said but it shows something like in code view of the browser(ctrl+u)...<a href="<?php echo $label; ?>" >some text</a>
..it's just display the variable instead of pulling it's result :(

Answer (score 1):

I just put the link in something like

```
$SomeLink="index.php";
```

then use the

```
echo "<div>$nam Your Password Could not be Found
<br><br>
<a href=$SomeLink>Click and Return to Login Page</a>
</div>";
```

with the double quotes on the ends it works on IE, Edge and Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working because you encapsulated the variable with a single quote. Use a double quote to retrieve the value of the variable rather than the literal variable text.

```
$outputListdata1 .= "<div class='content1'><a href='$label'>$title</a></div><div class='content2'>$info</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi use it in the same way as you use $title:

```
$outputListdata1 .= '<div class="content1">
                        <a href= "'.$label.'" >' .$title. '</a>
                        </div><!-- end of content1 -->

                        <div class="content2">
                        ' .$info. '
                        </div><!-- end of content2 -->';
```

Comment: kindly answer this one too.. how to write this <a href= "www.example.com/'.$label.'" >' .$title. '</a> is it right?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href = "$label" >' .$title. '</a>
```

Just paste that line of code in line 14 and this will work for you guaranteed ;)

Comment: thanks i got that one can you help how to insert another variable in the same href..for example: <a href = "$label"."$info" >' .$title. '</a> is it right way?

Comment: @kyan2020 It depends on what is required in href...
the way you write above line it will only concatenate two variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die (mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("databasename") or die (mysql_error()); 
$sqlmydata = mysql_query("SELECT id, label, title, info, body FROM table LIMIT 0,10");  // Build the Output Section Here 
$outputListdata1 = ''; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqldata))
{      
  $id = $row["id"];    
  $label = $row["label"];    
  $title = $row["title"];    
  $info = $row["info"]; 
} // close while loop 
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>    
<head>  
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
  <title>my site</title> 
</head>  
<body>     
  <div class="container">    
    <div class="content1">    
      <a href= "#" ><?php echo $title;?></a>    
    </div><!-- end of content1 -->               
    <div class="content2">          
      <?php echo $info;?>          
    </div>    
  </div><!-- end of container --> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot you friend to spend your time to help and answer my question. that's ok :)